# Android listview for chat application with text messages and files

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-progressbar, notifydatasetchanged

I am developing chat application in android. I am Using listview to show text messages. Now I am going to implement file transfer in the chat application. File transfer works like, When **Device A** transfers any file, the file is uploaded to server and the corresponding download url is sent to **Device B** in the form of text message. In **Device B** chat listview I am going to show button to download that file. When user clicks on the particular button in listview, I want to download file using async task meanwhile I want to show progress bar in listview . While downloading the file if **Device B** gets any other text message , I have to refresh listview using notifyDatasetChanged to show the new message.

How to keep the progressbar without affected from notifyDatasetChanged?

Also is there any other good solution to to show download url in chat listview and to download the file and show it to user?

Comment: When your are sending data from Device A first store it in db and display on listview..and send data using back ground service..and receiving also same, receive data using background service..and do periodic check.

Answer (score 0):

on top of my mind, i can think of it this way...

1. make a custom adapter with the list view item you want and include a progress bar in it.
2. set the default visibility of this progress bar as GONE
3. whenever the user starts to download a file, make this progress bar VISIBLE and make it GONE again after the file has been downloaded.

this way, your progress will be made available on request when the file download is in progress...